# Count the number of parameters in query string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I count the number of parameters query strings passed? e.g.

```
www.abc.com/product.html?product=furniture&&images=true&&stocks=yes
```

I want to be able to get the answer as 3
`1. product=furniture`
`2. images=true`
`3. stocks=yes`

```
var url = window.location.href;
var arr = url.split('=');
console.log(url.length)
```

Comment: The easiest way is to just split them by `&` `window.location.search.split('&').length` but in your url there is variables with `&` in name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use String's `match`:

```
var matches = str.match(/[a-z\d]+=[a-z\d]+/gi);
var count = matches? matches.length : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

first get the location of a question mark character `?` in the required url

```
var pos = location.href.indexOf("?");
if(pos==-1) return [];
query = location.href.substr(pos+1);
```

then get the array of parameters:

```
var result = {};
query.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
    var item = part.split("=");
    result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
});
```

Then count the length of result as

```
result.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using express you can use 
 `Object.keys(req.query).length`

see here: [How to get number of request query parameters in express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600800/how-to-get-number-of-request-query-parameters-in-express-js)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the search variable in the document.location object to get the search string and then use a match on the '=' symbols to get a count (see example below)

```
var paramCount = document.location.search.match(/=/g).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) interface that provides utility methods to work with the query string of a URL?

Something like that:

```js
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url_var = new URL(url_string);
var params = url_var.searchParams;
var param_count = 0;
for (const [key, value] of params.entries()) {param_count++;}
```