# How to get number of request query parameters in express.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, express

At the moment I have to check every potentially existing parameter separately.

```
if (req.query.param1 != undefined ) {
}
if (req.query.param2 != undefined ) {
}
if (req.query.param3 != undefined ) {
}
...
```

Comment: I am testing with `curl -X GET localhost:9090/mypath?param1=123&param2=321`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get all query parameter:

```
Object.keys(req.query)
```

To get number of all params:

```
Object.keys(req.query).length
```

Then you can iterate through all parameters:

```
for(p in req.query) {
  //... do something
}
```

UPD:

surround your request with quotes to make right query

`curl -X GET "localhost:9090/mypath?param1=123&param2=321"`

without quotes the `&` in terminal makes the command run in the background.

Comment: `console.log(Object.keys(req.query));` returns only `[ 'param1' ]`

Comment: `Object.keys(req.query).length` returns `1`

Comment: @MatkoKlaic what's your `GET` query?

Comment: `curl -X GET localhost:9090/mypath?param1=123&param2=321`

Comment: I am handling `/mypath` with express.js Router object.

Comment: @MatkoKlaic I've tried, just surround with quotes your request,  curl -X GET "localhost:9090/mypath?param1=123&param2=321"

Answer (score 1):

You want the number of non-undefined params right?
It is as simple as this;

```
var no = 0;
for (var key in req.query) { 
    if(req.query[key]) no++;
}
```

Comment: This piece of code causes `ReferenceError: key is not defined`.

Comment: How about this way? Use `var key`

Answer (score 0):

If you hit `/mypath?param1=5&param2=10`, then the `request.query` will yield `{param1: 5, param2:10}`.

This means that the `request.query` is a JavaScript object with the `key` as the name of the param, and `value` as the value of the param. Now you can do anything with it as you want: Find the length or iterate over it as follows:

```
for (var key in request.query) {
  if (request.query.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + request.query[key]);
  }
}
```

Finding only the `length` might not work for you that well because you may have `param1` and `param3`, with `param2` missing. Iterating will be better IMO.